# Copy Content Files from VS 2017 to Windows 10 IoT Core for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am developing an application for Windows Core for Raspberry Pi 3 using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

I am quite new to the platform and trying to copy some content files to Raspberry.
I have tried changing the type of my files to "Content" and "Copy Always" in the property window.

However, I am not able to find where these files are copied and how can I refer these files in my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am not able to find where these files are copied and how
>   can I refer these files in my code.

You can get the path like this:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
```

And access these files like this:

```
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///copyfile test.txt"));
        string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

For more information you can reference "[File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)" and "[Create, write, and read a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files#reading-from-a-file)".